# How to insert value in table which is not present in input file for sqlldr?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-loader

Consider the table structure as below:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE
(
   FIELD_1             VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
   SYS_CREATION_DATE   DATE         NOT NULL,
   FIELD_2             VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
   FIELD_3             VARCHAR2(25)
)
```

Input file : input.txt - It does not contain SYS_CREATION_DATE it has FIELD_1,FIELD_2,FIELD_3

```
111111111111111,12345,67890
```

Control file : control.txt

```
load data
infile "input.txt"
append
into table TEST_TABLE
fields terminated by ','
trailing nullcols
(
   FIELD_1                    ,
   SYS_CREATION_DATE       "SYSDATE",
   FIELD_2            ,
   FIELD_3
)
```

Now after running

```
sqlldr userid="uid/pass@ins" control="control.txt"
```

The below entry is inserted

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| FIELD_1         | SYS_CREATION_DATE   | FIELD_2 | FIELD_3 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 111111111111111 | 5/9/2017 2:03:03 PM | 67890   |         |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

The FIELD_3 is coming in as NULL, I presume this is because the alignment of fields is different in the file and table.

So what can be done to get the entry inserted as below

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| FIELD_1         | SYS_CREATION_DATE   | FIELD_2 | FIELD_3 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 111111111111111 | 5/9/2017 2:03:03 PM | 12345   | 67890   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this ,This should work

```
load data
infile "input.txt"
append
into table TEST_TABLE
fields terminated by ','
trailing nullcols
(
   FIELD_1                ,
   FIELD_2                ,
   FIELD_3                ,
  SYS_CREATION_DATE       "SYSDATE"
)
```